# Вывести результат sql запроса в две строки

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  phone VARCHAR(45),
  email VARCHAR(100),
  date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
);

CREATE TABLE order_products (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  order_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  code VARCHAR(255),
  qty INT(5) NOT NULL,
  total DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(id)
);
```

Необходимо выбрать две группы заказов:

1. в списке продуктов заказа есть продукт с code='key'
2. в списке продуктов заказа нет продукта с code='key'

Для каждой группы средние значения (средний чек, среднее кол. товаров и т.д.).
Трудность заключается в выводе результата в две строки.

Comment: В чём трудность-то? `query1 UNION ALL query2`

Comment: Большое спасибо!